# Python Process exiting without warning or error after ThreadPoolExecutor finishes

Tags: python, debugging, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I a have a pretty standard python threadpool implementation in my code. But suddenly I have started finding an issue where the process exits after running the function:

```
def func_with_threadpool_execution():
    executors_list = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        executors_list.append(
            executor.submit(func1, arg)
        )
        executors_list.append(
            executor.submit(func2, arg)
        )
        executors_list.append(
            executor.submit(func3, arg)
        )

    executors_list = list(executors_list)
    data_1 = executors_list[0].result()
    data_2 = executors_list[1].result()
    data_3 = executors_list[2].result()

    data_4, data_5 = collect_data_from_other_sources()
    processed_data = process_all_data(data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5)
    aggregated_data = aggregate_all_data(processed_data)
    return aggregated_data
```

This function is called by some other function in the program.
Here I am facing a weird situation. The entire python process exits without any exception or warnings when the function `func_with_threadpool_execution` returns. When I log `aggregated_data` before returning it, it gets logged. But when I do `print(func_with_threadpool_execution)` the python process is already exited and nothing gets printed.

I found that this issue is occurring in my ubuntu system only and working in my mac, and other ubuntu systems too. It was working in my system till the last few days. (And after that I have only shifted from unity to gnome. I dont know how that can in any way lead to such a problem but thought I should mention it.)
Also, when I run it after removing threadpool executor, it works.

Can somebody help me out in fixing it or just point me in the right direction as to how to debug it. TIA.

I am running python 3.7.2 on ubuntu 16.04. Have the same setup for almost a year. And this is being called within flask.

Should I go about reinstalling python?

Comment: I had to reinstall python to fix it.